# Get the highest updated ID of a multi row update

Tags: sql-server

**Update:** I am using Sql Server 2008 R2.

I am going to update a large number of rows and to avoid unnecessary locking I will do this in matches of around a thousand lines per update.

Using SET `ROWCOUND` I can limit the update to 1000 lines and using `WHERE ID > x` I can set which batch it should run.

But for this to work I need to know the highest ID from the just processed batch.

I could user `OUTPUT`to return all affected ID's and find the highest one on code but I would like to be able to return just the highest ID.

I tried this

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM (
    UPDATE mytable
    SET maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(salesvalue) FROM sales WHERE cid = t.id GROUP BY cid)
    OUTPUT inserted.id
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE au.userid > 0
) updates(id)
```

But it gives me this error
`A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.`

BUT if I try to insert the result into a table directly it is valid

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM (
    UPDATE mytable
    SET maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(salesvalue) FROM sales WHERE cid = t.id GROUP BY cid)
    OUTPUT inserted.id
    FROM mytable t
    WHERE au.userid > 0
) updates(id)

drop table #temp
```

Is there any workaround to this and can anyone explain why I can insert the result into a table but not just return the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT USE SET ROWCOUNT for this (or, at all), as BOL says:

> Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and
> UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server!
>
> Do not use SET
> ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development
> work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Also, for
> DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements that currently use SET ROWCOUNT,
> we recommend that you rewrite them to use the TOP syntax.

You could do it with a table variable, too:

```
DECLARE @Log TABLE (id INT NOT NULL);

UPDATE TOP 1000 mytable
SET maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(salesvalue) FROM sales WHERE cid = t.id GROUP BY cid)
OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @Log
FROM mytable t
WHERE au.userid > 0

SELECT maxid = MAX(id)
FROM @Log
```

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2 does not seem to like TOP with Updates, it generates Incorrect syntax.